# Database creation/saving with a many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, has-many

I have two tables, item and category, and a joined table named Items_Categories. The one restriction I have is that an item HAS to have a category.

In my Item Model, I have this code:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :items_categories
  has_many :item_orders
  has_many :orders, through: :item_orders
```

even though categories is not a column in my Items database.

Here's my ItemsCategory model:

```
class ItemsCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Here's my Category Model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items_categories
  has_many :items, through: :items_categories  
end
```

In my test, I have this issue:

```
  test 'it is valid' do
    category = Category.create(name: "hot beverages")
    item = category.items.create(title: "fjdkasf", description: "fjakdsf", price: 20901290)

    assert item.valid?
  end
```

Basically, this test fails because I cannot create an item until it item.categories is not nill. But the validation doesn't pass until I create the item in item_categories. So... what do I do? Basically I can't pass the validation when I create the item because the item doesn't yet have a category. But I want to make sure that every time I create an item, it has an associated item. So what do I do?

Comment: please post the association code section of your `ItemCategory` and `Item` model, I have a hunch that you're missing the `:inverse_of` option in your association....

Answer (score 0):

Validation with `has_many :through` relations can be tricky sometimes, there's a hint in the [`has_many :through`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) documentation that you should define the `inverse_of` attribute on your join model:

> If you are going to modify the association (rather than just read from
>   it), then it is a good idea to set the :inverse_of option on the
>   source association on the join model. This allows associated records
>   to be built which will automatically create the appropriate join model
>   records when they are saved. (See the 'Association Join Models'
>   section above.)

```
class ItemsCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item, inverse_of: :items_categories 
  belongs_to :category, inverse_of: :items_categories
end
```

To be honest, I'm not 100% sure this will fix it, but give it a try and report back.